# Преобразование из unsigned char в char

Tags: c++

В *OpenSSL* есть функция:

```
unsigned char* MD5(const unsigned char* d, unsigned long n, unsigned char* md);
```

Проблема в том, что мне необходимо сделать ввод текста через консоль и сохранение его в строку, чтобы использовать её в качестве аргумента для `MD5()` и получения значения хэш-функции, но

```
istream& std::istream::getline(char* s, streamsize n);
```

принимает только аргументы типа `char*`.

Как решить проблему несоответствия типов?

Comment: (unsigned char*)charPtr вас определенно спасет.

Answer (score 2):

Делайте каст, в данном случае это полезно и безопасно.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);

const char* chars = str.data();
const unsigned char* data_bytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(chars);

std::array<unsigned char, 16> hash;
MD5(data_bytes, str.size(), &hash[0]);
```

Comment: можно даже без явного преобразования обойтись

Comment: Что еще за "каст"?